# Flutter: How do I detect tab onclick when the current tab is selected?

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbarcontroller

While I can detect tab changes with:

```
controller.addListener((){
   print('my index is'+ controller.index.toString());
});
```

How do I detect if the same tab is tapped? I'd like to have an action when user clicks on the home tab to go to the top of the scroll page while user is at home.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement to use onTap method in TabBar class.

```
TabBar(
   onTap: (index) {
      print(controller.index);
      print(index);
      if (controller.index == index) {
         print('Same Tab Clicked');
      }
   },
   tabs: [
      ...
   ]

});
```

Comment: controller.index and index will always be the same.  I could however use controller.indexIsChanging to check inside onTap!

Comment: hm.. I've already tested whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onItemSelected` option in your `TabView` widget.